# CKEditor set width

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor 4 with inline editing. I want to set custom height to the CKEditor toolbar that appears. I looked around and found a solution

```
config.height = 300;
config.width = 550;
```

I wrote the above two lines in the config.js file. But sadly, its not working for me.

Any Ideas? Or inline editing doesnt support custom height?

**EDIT :**

I alsp tried this in my js

```
editor.resize( 900, 300 );
```

but no luck

Comment: I have played only a bit with inline feature, so there are probably better ways to do this, but dimensions of toolbar in inline mode seem to be controled by layout of buttons. So to have it of certain width just put line break after desired button and height will be sum of button rows. Would there be any point of having toolbar take space without buttons?

Comment: the thing is that, if i have too many buttons, it goes outside my containers. As you mentioned, i would like to have my controls divided in two rows, so that my editor expands vertically, not horizontally

Comment: so does standard toolbar linebreak '/' work for you?

Comment: I dont know about that and how to implement it. Could you give me an example ?

Comment: Ok i found an example. It is working. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: can you post your comment as an answer so that i can accept

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem. BTW, you can write the answer yourself since you found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the linebreak '/' as Zee suggested in the comment area.

For example:

```
  config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker', 'basicstyles', 'cleanup'] },
        '/',
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align' ] },
        { name: 'links' },
        ...
]
```

The linebreak will break the buttons into two rows.

Comment: as you can see in the commments, thats what I am doing already.

Comment: @MandeepJain, Yes, but writing an answer can help other people who encounter the same problem see the solution faster. So they won't jump to the conclusion that this is an unsolved question. You can write an answer and I will be more than happy to delete mine. Cheers